# Patterns for destructuring "Function" function arguments

Tags: pure-function, argument-patterns

I want to define a function for finding a Jacobian matrix of pure vector function of vector argument. I try

```
J[Function[vars_List /; VectorQ[vars], funs_]] := Function @@ Evaluate /@ {vars, D[funs, {vars}]}

A = Function[{x, y, \[Theta], v, \[Omega]}, {v Cos[\[Theta]], v Sin[\[Theta]], \[Omega], 0, 0}]

J[A]
```

, this code works great but I get Function::flpar message.

Is it possible to achieve same result correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your code. A minimal change to make it work would be:

```
ClearAll[J];
J[HoldPattern[Function[vars_List /; VectorQ[vars], funs_]]] := 
   Function @@ Evaluate /@ {vars, D[funs, {vars}]}
```

The reason you need `HoldPattern` has to do with how lhs. of assignment is evaluated during the assignments.

However, this is not all. The code as it stands has problems in the form of evaluation leaks, particularly when the variables have global values. A safer version of the code would be:

```
ClearAll[J];
J[HoldPattern[Function[vars_List /; VectorQ[Unevaluated[vars]], body_]]] := 
   Block[vars, Function @@ {vars, D[body, {vars}]}]
```

where I used `Unevaluated` to prevent evaluation of `vars` during pattern-matching, `Block` to prevent evaluation of `vars` during function construction on the r.h.s., and removed `Evaluate`, which isn't needed. Note also that, while I left your `VectorQ` test for didactic purposes, it isn't needed either, because you already test that the arguments are in a list.

Personally I'd use yet different code:

```
ClearAll[J];
J[HoldPattern[Function[vars : {__Symbol}, body_]]] :=
   Block[vars, Function @@ {vars, D[body, {vars}]}]
```

which is simpler and avoids some of the problems of the previous versions, while being yet more robust.